# Is using Activity necessary to work with google's API?

Tags: java, android, google-api-client

Right now I'm trying to work with google's API for real-time multiplayer and I'm looking over an example file called "skeletonActivity.java".(this is an example project)

I've noticed the following:

```
public class someClass extends Activity
implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
View.OnClickListener, RealTimeMessageReceivedListener,
RoomStatusUpdateListener, RoomUpdateListener, OnInvitationReceivedListener{
```

I know that **[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)** is a super class that the class SkeletonActivity is inheriting from, but the more I read about activity the more I realize that it seems to be the base of an *entire* application framework.

From what I've read, the examples that Google has provided continually mention using "Activity" in conjunction with the GoogleApiClient, but for my cases I just want to utilize the client and not Activity. Do I need to inherit from Activity to use the client API?

*note:* If it sounds confusing that I'm asking this question it is because I'm making a game using "GameMaker:Studio" and all I need to access are the interfaces that allow me to make use of the `com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer`(realtime) library. This is so I can write an extension library to access the api functionality.

Answer (score 0):

A skeleton is a special way to implement a module or an interface. Read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(computer_programming)

The class you've mentioned is not from the Android API, it seems instead to be copied from an exsample. Because I don't know about the example I only can assume that this was a pseudo device to simulate a multiplayer without actually runnning the application on a (second) device.

Comment: What class does not exist? Activity was the class I was asking that needed to be inherited, because it seemed as though I shouldn't have to inherit from it. I edited the question a little bit to provide more information.

Comment: I've meant the class `SkeletonActivity` (or by now `someClass`, which by the way does not follow the convention for class names in Java), your edits came after my answer ;)

Comment: It does not follow the convention because I did not Capitalize the first letter? If you know it is possible to use the googleApi without the extension class `activity` that would be very helpful.

Comment: No it is not possible! The `Activity` is the main class in an Android application to interact with the user (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) So you have to deal with it in order to make any app usable by a person.